# How to sync local feature branch (which is off of old version) with the latest version?

Tags: git

1. I have a local branch feature2 off of feature1 (v1).
2. So local feature2 is v1 as well and feature2 has never been pushed
   yet.
3. But now feature1 has a newer version in remote v2.
4. And I git fetch and merge feature1, and my local feature1 is v2

**Q: how to make feature2 be synced with v2?**

Summary:
In Local:

```
feature1: v1
feature2: v1  ( off of feature1)

feature1: v2  ( now )
feature2: v1  ( modified and added some files based on v1)
              Q: how to make feature2 be synced with v2?
```

Comment: Fetch doesn't actually update your local copy of the branch. That's what git pull does. Once you have the changes pulled locally, you can `git merge feature1` from feature2, or do a rebase if that's how you like to do things.

Answer (score 1):

In you local since feature1 is already on the latest version, you can do the following to sync feature2.

Checkout to you feature2 branch in local and then execute the rebase command. "*git rebase feature1*". This will merge all commits in feature1 to feature2 and put the additional commits you have on feature2 on the top.

https://www.simplilearn.com/what-is-git-rebase-command-article